# Esxi 6.5 WD Sata RED HDD Dead Slow

Tags: vmware-esxi

Using ESXI 6.5 Update 3 HP Image on HP ML350 G6 2X Xeon CPU & 128GB RAM, i know G6 is old but i can only afford that.

I don't have SAS drives but my G6 has 7 SATA ports, installed ESXI on 1TB SSD and added 2TB WD RED hdd as storage, when i create vm on SSD drive it's really fast and stable (as expected), but when i create an vm on 2tb storage disk even the creation of vm tooks arround 10minutes, it's same with copying something to 2tb hdd.

Removed esxi's SSD and connected 2tb hdd directly to server as standalone to see if my hdd is bad and installed windows on it, it's installed very quickly and it works just fine.

When i searched about this problem i found out some users experienced same problem and they fixed with disabling native AHCI driver with `esxcli system module set --disable=true --module=vmw_ahci` but didn't work for me, also on some subjects users mentioning about legacy ahci driver but i couldn't figure it out what does mean legacy ahci driver.

Could you guys give me a hand about what makes dead slow my hdd and is there a fix for it?

Comment: SATA controllers are generally slow on ESXi. You should get a SAS controller, even if you continue using the SATA drives. You might also want to get faster HDDs though, WD RED are just 5400 rpm.

Comment: @Zac67 thanks for information, SAS drives are really expensive in my country, what about SAS to SATA converters, do you think it will do the trick?

Comment: No need for anything like that, with rare exceptions you can run SATA drives on all SAS (RAID) controllers - just don't mix SATA and SAS within an array.

Comment: @Zac67 oh i didn't know that, i know sas and & sata sockets are similiar but didn't try to use sata on sas before,actually 2 weeks ago i see an HP380 G8 server which it's first drive on sas array was SSD and i wondered how did they make it work, i think they just simply plug it in huh? i have an old 60gb ssd drive, let me try to plug-in to sas socket and see what will happen :) Thanks man.